# ¿Como puedo cambiar el color del enfoque de los item en un NavigationRailItem en Kotlin?

Tags: android, visual-studio, kotlin, programación-móvil

Estoy empezando a usar NavigationRailItem en Kotlin y por defecto el viene con un efecto o color translucido cuando se navega sin seleccionar los items mediante un PAD, por lo tanto, quiero saber si existe alguna forma que se pueda cambiar ese color translucido por otro color?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Este es un ejemplo, el color naranja es cuando esta seleccionado.
- El segundo icono se ve el color translucido como gris que es cuando se navega y muestra donde esta ubicado el cursor o la navegación antes de seleccionar. Ese es el color que quiero cambiar para adaptarlo a la app que estoy elaborando. Se puede?

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta para que puedas verlo y que puedas entender mi idea.